# Adding Tensorflow AAR using Gradle doesn't work. I get an error

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-gradle-plugin

I know adding this should download the Tensorflow AAR so I can call the Android functions for tensorflow.

However, on my custom project. I get this error:

```
Error:(8, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments 
[org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+] on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I am suppose to compile with "org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+"

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
}
```

What do I need to do to install Tensorflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Error:(8, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments 
>   [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+] on object of type 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

You should add **`tensorflow:tensorflow`** in **module-level** **`build.gradle`** section instead of **`app-level`**.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I can now import TensorFlow into code and I can also declare Tensorflow variables. It should be enough to know it works.

Comment: @poetryrocksalot glad to hear. Move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing in your terminal is related to your Gradle build configuration. It seems that the `compile()` method cannot be found for the arguments you've provided. This is likely because the `compile()` method has been deprecated and removed in recent versions of Gradle.

The `compile()` method was used to add dependencies to your project, but it has been replaced with the `implementation()` or `api()` methods. You should replace `compile` with `implementation` or `api` in your `build.gradle` file.

Here's an example of how you might change your code:

```
dependencies {
    // Old way
    // compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'

    // New way
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
}
```

This change should resolve the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Add maven repository in gradle like this,

```
repositories {
    ......
    maven {
        url 'https://google.bintray.com/tensorflow'
    }
}
```